# Comparing two arrays?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I want to compare two arrays with the following setup, but don't know how using code.

Have one array, arrayOne, compare with another array, arrayTwo.

Once the difference of the two arrays are found, add those differences to arrayOne and remove everything from arrayTwo.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If array1 has unique values:**

```
NSArray *array1=@[@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D"];
NSArray *array2=@[@"A",@"E",@"C"];

NSMutableOrderedSet *set1=[[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc]initWithArray:array1];
NSMutableOrderedSet *set2=[[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc]initWithArray:array2];
[set1 unionOrderedSet:set2];

array1=[set1 array];
array2=@[];

NSLog(@"array1: %@,  array2: %@",array1,array2);
```

Output:

> array1: (
>           A,
>           B,
>           C,
>           D,
>           E
>       ), 
>        array2: (
>       )

**If array1 doesn't has unique values:**

```
NSMutableArray *unionArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array1];
for (NSString *element in array2) {  //compared only for string, if it is some other object need to compare them.
    if (![array1 containsObject:element]) {
        unionArray[unionArray.count]=element;
    }
}
array1=unionArray;
array2=@[];
NSLog(@"array1: %@, array2: %@",array1,array2);
```

Output:

> array1: (
>       A,
>       B,
>       C,
>       D,
>       A,
>       E ),   array2: ( )

Comment: This will work on the condition that every element of `array1` is unique. Neat trick though to preserve order.

Comment: @Vishal: So why should i keep mine one there ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Hope this will helpful to you.

```
NSMutableArray *array1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil];

NSMutableArray *array2 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Two", @"Four", @"One", nil];

NSMutableArray *intermediate = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array2];

[intermediate removeObjectsInArray:array1];

for(int i = 0; i < [intermediate count]; i++)
{
    [array1 addObject:[intermediate objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I edit the answer. it's OutPut is : One,Two,Three, Four.